# JQuery storing data to check later

Tags: javascript, jquery

Class .cell is 9 cells in a table for a tic tac toe board. Clicking X and O has been working but I am trying to check and only allow and X or O if the cell *hasn't been used yet.*

I have tried using the JQuery data property, using a key and a value, and only using a value.

```
$('.cell').on('click', function () {
if (currentTurn === 'X' && (!$(this).data('already-played', 'yes'))) {
  $(this).text('X')
  $(this).data('already-played', 'yes')
  currentTurn = 'O'
} else {
  $(this).text('O')
  $(this).data('already-played', 'yes')
  currentTurn = 'X'
}
```

Is the data property viable for something like this or might someone point out how to tweak this?

Comment: It seems like your conditional statement is a bit off. Consider when it is player X's turn and he clicks the cell that has already been played. Then the text is set to 'O' and now it is X's turn again. Does that make sense?

You could restructure your conditional statement to first check whose turn it is. Then, inside that conditional statement, put another that check to see if the cell has already been played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace :

```
!$(this).data('already-played', 'yes')
```

By :

```
$(this).data('already-played')!=='yes'
```

Since when you pass two arguments to the `data()` function, it will attach the second parameter as value to the first one, So the `yes` will be affected to `data-already-played` attribute.

**NOTE:** You should review your logic here, I suggest the following condition structure instead, so you could check for both choices if the cell is available :

```
$('.cell').on('click', function () {
    if ( $(this).data('already-played')!=='yes' ) {
        if( currentTurn === 'X' ){
          $(this).text('X')
          $(this).data('already-played', 'yes')
          currentTurn = 'O'
        } else {
          $(this).text('O')
          $(this).data('already-played', 'yes')
          currentTurn = 'X'
        }
    }else{
        alert( 'This cell was already filled.' );
    }
});
```